# Read variable from another function

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, function, flex3, variables

How can I access an variable from another function?

I have a function that sets and variable:

```
private function create () {
  var str:String = "hello";
}


private function take() {
  var message:String = str;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify whether or not the functions are in the same class or in different classes, but your main problem is [variable scope](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/variable_scope_for_new_programmers/). The **str** variable is defined inside the **create** function and therefore it's bound in the function's scope. You'll have to declare the variable in a larger scope.
If the functions are in the same class, try something along these lines:

```
private var str:String;

private function create () {
  str = "hello";
}


private function take() {
  var message:String = str;
}
```